# Play! framework + Ebean

Tags: java, database, orm, playframework-2.0, ebean

So I followed this official tutorial in order to integrate Ebean with my project:
http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaEbean

I tried to use `byId` method of `Finder` (to retrieve an object from the db)
but got this error:

> [RuntimeException: No JPA EntityManagerFactory configured for name [default]]

What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cant say what did you miss (some lines commented in `application.conf` ?) but to get it to work: browse play samples folder `play/samples/java/computer-database/` it uses `Ebean` so you can see what went wrong and make additional modifications to your own code.

**Edit:**

Going through some of the basic JPA and Ebean related error messages, I suspect that you have first tried to configure your project to use JPA but then switched to use Ebean instead. That's why you have now overlapping Ebean and JPA configurations in your project which are causing the problem.

Try this tutorial to learn to use Ebean: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaTodoList

Comment: Don't agree with you, DB config is simple and developer should know it (not only copy)

Comment: By copying contents I meant "looking help from other working Ebean project" maybe I wasn't descriptive enough - but its definitely helps in problem solving.

Comment: Yeap, especially Computer Database sample, however I sent the OP full instruction for DB config in some of previus post, so it can just start from that point :). Finally I prefer - rewriting from the sample instead of copy/paste, it also important to learn writing without typos (good IDE is best option)

Comment: Yes true, I would even suggest that using tutorial http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaTodoList would be better starting point for learning Ebean than url provided by post author.

Comment: yes. apparently I used a notation of JPA...
that is all about